# How to print the contents of a div without changing it's size on paper

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, printing

I have a php page which dynamically generates ID cards. So I want that when the user clicks a button that id card which is a  element gets printed. I tried all the answers available in Stackoverflow but all of them are changing size of the size of the div element whenever i am clicking the print button. Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p{
            font-size: 0.8em;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divid" style="border: 1px solid black;width: 30%;height: 250px;">
    <img src="images/logo_small.png" width="150px">
    <img src="images/indane.png" width="150px">
    <img style="float: right;" src="images/zayed.jpg">

    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>Name:</b>Zayed Ahmed</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>Desig:</b>Delivery Man</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>DOB:</b>07/09/1974</p>

    <div></div>

    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>Emp ID:</b> CTPL-01</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>PF Code:</b> XXXXXX</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>ESI Code:</b> 1234567890</p>

    <div></div>

    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>Address:</b>53, Alimuddin Street, Kolkata-700016</p>
    <div></div>

    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>Mobile :</b>93973878873</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block;"><b>Emergency:</b> 9763867657</p>
    <hr>
    <img style="float: left;margin-left: 20px;" src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=www.creativett.com&size=50x50">
    <img src="images/sign.png" style="float: right;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a code snippet please?
Not entirely sure of your problem yet

Comment: "but all of them are changing size of the size of the div element whenever i am clicking the print button. " There are many reasons why this would occur. It's most likely a CSS issue, but we need code to determine the actual problem.

Comment: As everyone is saying "show the code"... and a quick answer that might help is use inches as your measurement units.

Comment: what did you try , at least  , give us the input and what you are expected as results